# Check if any entry of first list is missing from second list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists of `String` objects. First list can have an object that can be splitted on basis of some delimiter. I want to get all those records of first list which are not present in second list.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A;H","B","C","D");
List collection = Arrays.asList("AH","B","D","E","F");
List<String> result = list.stream().filter(str -> !collection.contains(str)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code is partially correct according to my requirement. It outputs [A;H, C]. My requirement is it should only give output as C. Because if any of character or `String` object of "A;H" is present in second list. It should not be collected.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to eliminate the delimiting character and then compare the values for the existence. Here's how it looks.

```
private static final Pattern DELIMITER = Pattern.compile("\\W");

Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(collection);

List<String> nonExistingValues = list.stream()
    .map(s -> DELIMITER.splitAsStream(s).collect(Collectors.joining()))
    .filter(s -> !set.contains(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A much more compact approach which reuses the pattern as mentioned in the below comment would be,

```
List<String> nonExistingValues = list.stream()
    .map(s -> DELIMITER.matcher(s).replaceAll(""))
    .filter(s -> !set.contains(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Actually No, since what happens for other characters ? `A-H` or `AFH`, ...

Comment: I didn't get you? This works only if the delimiter is given. As in OPs post it is just a `;`. Moreover I don't think that we can programmatically solve this problem if you can have any number of arbitrary delimiters.

Comment: `.map(s -> DELIMITER.splitAsStream(s).collect(Collectors.joining()))` is the long way to do a `.map(s -> s.replaceAll("\\W", ""))`. If you worry about the costs of repeated `Pattern.compile` operations, you can also reuse the pattern as `.map(s -> DELIMITER.matcher(s).replaceAll(""))`.